# Input with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, loops, matplotlib, input

I've got a little problem with matplotlib.

I made an `input` function which allows me to decide whether I want to print my plot, save it or do both. The problem is with setting variables in my code:

I use input command:

```
Save_Print_SavPrin = input('Press s = Save, p = Print, b = Both: ')
```

But for that I need those variables `s`, `p` and `b`. The problem is that I cannot define them before I start defining my plots.

If I do something like this:

```
p = plt.show()
b = savefig1, savefig2, plt.show()
s = savefig1, savefig2
Save_Print_SavPrin = input('Press s = Save, p = Print, b = Both: ')
```

I'll get an obivous error that python doesn't know what is `savefig1` etc. and it will also prompt `plt.show()` too soon.

If I take this part of code to the last lines of my code and use this loop, so it will look like this:

Here goes code for plotting things, I have two figures so after `fig1` I have `savefig1`, and after `fig2` is this code, almost same, but different output file name.

```
savefig2 = plt.savefig('S:\Data\Python\Results\PlotB2.png', format='png', dpi=600)


p = plt.show()
b = savefig1, savefig2, plt.show()
s = savefig1, savefig2
Save_Print_SavPrin = input('Press s = Save, p = Print, b = Both: ')


if Save_Print_SavPrin == p:
    plt.show()
elif Save_Print_SavPrin == s:
    savefig1, savefig2
elif Save_Print_SavPrin == b:
    savefig1, savefig2, plt.show()
```

The problem here that when I put it in the last place in my code, every function will execute, then I will be asked by `input` what I want and I do those things again, which is pointless. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why not just move every call to `plt.savefig()` and `plt.show()` inside your `if` statements?

Comment: What do You mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not define a variable to `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig()` as those functions will be called at that point (and they return `None`). Instead, put those calls inside your `if` statements:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
# plot something here

fig2 = plt.figure()
# plot something else here

Save_Print_SavPrin = input('Press s = Save, p = Print, b = Both: ')
# If using Python 2.x, use raw_input()

if Save_Print_SavPrin == "p":
    print("Show figure")
    plt.show()

elif Save_Print_SavPrin == "s":
    print("Saving")
    fig1.savefig("Test1.png")
    fig2.savefig("Test2.png")

elif Save_Print_SavPrin == "b":
    print("Both")
    fig1.savefig("Test1.png")
    fig2.savefig("Test2.png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like a great idea, but when I press any key `p`, `s` or `b` i got an error that they are not defined.

Comment: Ah, you are using python2, then yes use `raw_input`. I will update my answer

Comment: Perfect everything works great exept one, as I have mentioned before, I have two figures, how to make in a loop so it will save figure 1 and figure 2?

Comment: @Hiddenguy I've updated my answer for saving multiple figures